# Cannot access disposed form despite creating it immediately prior

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a windows form (VB/.NET) that I want to open when I click a particular button. It opens correctly the first time, but after closing it and trying to re-open it I get this error:

"ObjectDisposedException was unhandle: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: frm8100VI"

Now, I create a new instance of the form right before calling it's show() method, so I don't know how it's disposed:

```
Dim form as New frm8100VI
form.show()
```

This code works correctly the first time it's called, but after closing the form once it will not work correctly again, saying the object has been disposed. To close the form all I do is call me.close()

Comment: There must be something in the frm8100VI constructor / events that invalidate itself, I think you should post more code about that class. Those lines obviously can't produce an object that is already disposed.

Comment: What confuses me is that the message indicates that the class itself has been disposed... frm8100VI is a class... I didn't think that was possible, I thought you could only dispose objects, or instances of a class. I checked the project for conflicting uses of that name but found none.

Comment: a form **is** a class; the error message `Cannot access a disposed object` says the object -- not class -- has been disposed.  try using a variable name like frm or f rather than a Type name (Form)

Comment: `To close the form all I do is call me.close()`  which disposes of it.  You cannot just do `form.Show` again, but create a new instance.  This is so that there is not an extra step required to actually dispose of them to free resources.

Comment: Plutonix - I do create a new instance... I do "Dim form As New frm8100VI" right before calling from.Show() each time. Changing the object name to "f" made no difference, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have your "Dim form as new frm8100VI" located in a space inside another object or in a public space where it never goes out of scope.

Once you have said "form.show", the user has worked with the form, closes the form.

At this point you cannot call "form.Show" again on the same form object (it is disposed).

You MUST reassign "form = New frm8011VI" again before you can call "form.show" (to re-iterate, after it has been disposed show fails)

If your trying to persist the information inside the "form" object then you should not actually close the form; in the form_unload event you show cancel the closing of the form and simply hide the form. If you do that you can call "form.Show" again without issue.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I am doing. The code provided occurs inside the handler to a button press, so every time the button is pressed I create a new instance of the frm8100VI class and then call it's show method. The button only works once, the second time I get the object disposed error.

Comment: You have a very strange issue there. Try placing break points in the major lifecycle events of the form itself: load, closing, close, dispose method, etc... and step through it to see what is happening. Check the call stack at each point to see what has triggered the break. Another thing that seems unlikely is if your forms are fairly complex has someone overridden the "show" routine maybe to try to do some kind of singleton form and is messing with you. just my last ideas.